# API design response object for Error Case

Tags: c#, rest, api, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a REST API that will give structured response Like this

```
public class ApiResponse
{
     //Success or Failure (this can be enum also) 
    public string Status;

    //Some message if any
    public string Message;

    //this is like Envelope of actual response (employee info , account Status etc.)
    public RenponseData Data;
}
```

And in case of Error/Exception I am planning to return something like this,

```
public class ApiError
{
    // Error Code
    public int Code;

    public string Description; 
}
```

So there are two different response object for 2 different cases.

My question is, **Is it good practice to return different structure object depending upon the success or failure of the request or API should return same structured object in every case**.

So for 2nd case my response Object might look like,

```
public class ApiResponse
{
     //Success or Failure (this can be enum also) 
    public string Status;

    //Some message if any
    public string Message;

    //this is like Envelope of actual response (employee info , account Status etc.)
    public RenponseData Data;

    public ErrorInfo ErrorData;
}

public class ErrorInfo
{
    // Error Code
    public int Code;

    public string Description; 
}
```

Please suggest.
Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: Use appropriate `HttpStatusCode` for success or failure. There are also out of the box `IHttpActionResult` like `BadRequest` or `Ok` to which you can pass through your error details. Don't reinvent the wheel I guess is the moral of the story here.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius thanks for responding. OK or ActionResult both method have a parameter where we can pass our custom object. Can this object be same in case of wrapper object either BadRequest of OK.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it good practice to return different structure object depending upon the success or failure of the request

Yes, it's fine.  The case of returning a representation of the resource, or the representation of [the status of the action](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) and the representation of the explanation of the [error situation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5).

General purpose components can distinguish the cases by examining the metadata of the response.

There are also ideas like [application/problem+json](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807), if you need "machine-readable details of errors"